# gstreamer tcpclientsink connection refused

Tags: linux, macos, wifi, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

Hi I am trying to stream data from linux box (Raspberry Pi) to Macbook pro using gstreamer-1.0.

On Raspberry-Pi (Linux)

```
pi@raspberrypi:[~]$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="video.h264" ! tcpclientsink host="192.168.1.140" port=5000
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSink:tcpclientsink0: Could not open resource for reading.
Additional debug info:
gsttcpclientsink.c(366): gst_tcp_client_sink_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSink:tcpclientsink0:
Failed to connect to host '192.168.1.140:5000': Connection refused
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

On Mac

```
punits@punits-mac:rover $ gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpserversrc port=5000 ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPServerSrc:tcpserversrc0: current-port = 5000
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
```

Using client and server both on raspberry-pi localhost works fine. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered two main reasons why I also had connection refused:

1. if host is not specified; tcpclientsink uses ipv6 instead of ipv4.
2. the server was not listening; which gives the "Connection Refused" error. You must launch the server first!

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in gstreamer0.10 by default the tcpserversrc listens on localhost only.
I guess that in gstreamer1.0 it might be the same.

Try to use property "host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" in order to specify your external ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `host` for `tcpserversink`:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpserversrc port=5000 host=0.0.0.0 ! fakesink
```

The `host` parameter is where your server accepts the requests from.

The `0.0.0.0` value means the server would accept requests from any address. If you don't set it then it defaults to the `localhost` which as a rule then resolves to `127.0.0.1`. It would imply the server accepts request from the same host, and refuses from others, as in your case.